# Adding constraint to several tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

If I have the following tables:

```
User(user_id, name)

Job(job_id,...)

Authorised(job_id,user_id) //a job is authorised to be done by 1 or more users

Work(user_id, job_id) //user working on a job
```

The question is: for the `Work` table I want to have a constraint saying that for all entries, the user should be authorised to work on the job. Is this possible to do (as it needs to look at the `Authroised` table as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with a foreign key relationship.

```
create unique index unq_authorised_job_user on Authorized(job_id, user_id);
```

(This is needed if the combination is not currently a primary key or unique.).

```
alter table Work add constraint foreign key (job_id, user_id) references Authorised(job_id, user_id)
```